# Fermat's little Theorem python

Tags: python

i am trying to implement Ferment's little Theorem via python. The value that returns does not give me a prime however. Any help is appreciated.
Apologies, the theorem states that in which for a random number of of times if a number is prime then any number generated less then it would give pow(a,value,x) == 1. The code below is an implementation of it.

The purpose of the code would be for function generate bit to create a 16 bit integer and run it via the theorem to prove if its a prime or not, if its a prime,return the value, if not call the function generatebit() again. Thank you for your time taken

```
import random            
def generatebit():
    x = random.getrandbits(16)
    x = int(x)
     if little(x):
       return x




def little(x):
 value = x -1   
 for i in xrange(50000):
        # check for a total of 50000 times to reduce chances
        a = random.getrandbits(15)
        if pow(a,value,x) != 1:
            generatebit()
            break

 return True         


a=generatebit()
print a
```

Comment: I think you'd greatly extend your target audience if you'd insert a small paragraph about what Ferment's little Theorem does, what you'd therefore expect, and what you get instead...

Comment: please fix the indentation so that your code is at least runnable

Comment: you mean [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem), don't you?

Comment: ok even knowing the theorem now, it's not clear to me what you're trying to do here. I'm not voting to close but there's a gap between the theorem and how you're trying to prove(?) it - that's important information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what the theorem is (see my comment), I can still tell you that there are some issues in your code.

- you first call `generatebits`, which generates a random number. then if `little(x)`, you return that value. Since however `little(x)` is always true, what this code does is create a random value and return it
- Whatever happens within you `for` loop is totally without effect. all you do is assign a value to a variable `a` that never gets read, and call a function that returns a value you don't read